# Change of variable in $\int_0^∞ \int_0^∞ t^{x-1} s^{y-1} e^{-(s+t)} dsdt$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, gamma-function, change-of-variable

I want to evaluate $$\int_0^∞ \int_0^∞ t^{x-1} s^{y-1} e^{-(s+t)} dsdt$$ which I need for some relation of gamma function. The book is suggested change of variables $s = uv$ and $t = u(1 - v)$ and claimed that $0 < s, t <∞$ implies $0 < u < ∞$ and $0 < v < 1$. I want to know how *rigorously* this change of variables works :

1- Intuitively, $0 < u < ∞$ and $0 < v < 1$ when $0 < s, t <∞$ for example $v$ cannot be less than $0$ because of $s = uv$ and cannot be greater than $1$ because of $t = u(1 - v)$ but why this implies sets of all $v$ is *not* a proper subset of $[0,1]$? Mathematically, how one proves $0 < s, t <∞$ implies $0 < u < ∞$ and $0 < v < 1$?

2- When I studied advanced calculus, in one variable there was always a bijection when change of variables imposed, but in two variables the book used always intuition for a One-to-one correspondence. How to establish a bijection between two sheets u-v and s-t? A general method of construction of a bijection in two dimension (to include this special) would be even better because I can learn finally the method that the book missed to express.

Comment: Wait. Isn't it $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)$. Becuase $\int_0^∞ \int_0^∞ t^{x-1} s^{y-1} e^{-(s+t)} dsdt=\int_0^∞ \int_0^∞ t^{x-1}e^{-t}s^{y-1} e^{-s} dsdt=\int_0^∞ t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt\int_0^{\infty}s^{y-1} e^{-s}ds=\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)$

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar, yes it is (actually whole chapter is about Gamma)! But my question is about justifying change of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve for $u$ and $v$ in terms of $s$ and $t$.  Get $u=s+t$ and $v=\frac{s}{s+t}$.

This immediately tells you what the ranges are for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: For use of change of variables, one needs a bijection between u-v and s-t planes/sheets, right? How do you make this bijection function generally which applies for this example too?

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for.  The answer I gave allows you to use the u and v limits as you presented.

Comment: I meant my 2nd question. One needs to confirm that new variables domain has a bijective correspondence with the old one to use change of variable theorem.

Comment: For each (u,v) pair a unique (s,t) pair can be computed and vice versa.